# is dispatcher IO always run in IO.Thread? (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutine

I am learning coroutine with android.
and i have curious dispatcher.io
the book says like when i use

> withcontext(dispatcher.IO)

OR

> lifecycleScope(Dispatcher.IO)

it will run on IO.Thread.

but other parts in book say multi-coroutines can run in main thread.

dispatcher.io can run in main-thread(UI Thread in android studio)?

Comment: I'm not really sure what do you ask. `Dispatchers.IO` uses IO threads (actually, it shares threads with `Dispatchers.Default`) and `Dispatchers.Main` uses main/UI thread. No, when using `Dispatchers.IO` we don't run the code in the main thread.

Comment: When you use Dispatcher.IO ,everything within withContext block will run in bacground thread not in main thread.

Comment: thanks i just want to sure about that.

Comment: "multi-coroutines can run in main thread." Can you quote exactly what the book said? Note, you can run suspend functions on the main Dispatcher fine as long as they're not blocking suspend functions (which are not supposed to exist).

Comment: @Tenfour04 I think by "multi-coroutines" the OP simply meant "many coroutines".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher, the block, it is applied to, runs in background (worker) `Thread`. Here are some examples:

1. Using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)` we can run some long running code or network request in the background(worker) thread. In this case we must mark the functions as suspend:

   ```
   suspend fun doWorkInBackground(): String = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
      // long running code
      // return some result
      "Some Result"
   }
   ```
2. Using `launch` coroutine builder. In this case coroutine will be running on `Dispatchers.IO` dispatcher in background thread, and it is not possible to update UI from such coroutine (we need to switch coroutine context to `Dispatchers.Main` to be able to update UI):

   ```
   lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) { 
      // invoke some suspend functions or execute potentially long running code

      // to switch context in this case and be able to update UI
      withContext(Dispatchers.Main) {
          // updateUI
      }
   }
   ```

In the second example to avoid switching coroutine context to `Dispatchers.Main` it is possible to run a coroutine on `Dispatchers.Main` dispatcher and update UI from there:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
    // call some suspend function, but shouldn't call non-suspend 
    // long running code from here because it will block the Main Thread and UI may freeze
    val result = doWorkInBackground()
        
    // Update UI
    textView.text = result
}
```